# How to find the minimum, maximum and average value of all property of array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays, json

I have an array of objects with different values in it, I want to find the min, max, and average of the properties in that array

for eg if I have an array

```js
const array = [{
    "a": "-0.06",
    "b": "0.25",
    "c": "-0.96",
    "d": "-0.14"
  },
  {
    "a": "-0.37",
    "b": "0.01",
    "c": "-0.77",
    "d": "-0.09"
  },
  {
    "a": "0.01",
    "b": "0.88",
    "c": "-0.53",
    "d": "-0.28"
  },
  {
    "a": "0.53",
    "b": "-0.62",
    "c": "0.02",
    "d": "0.74"
  },
  {
    "a": "0.79",
    "b": "-0.39",
    "c": "0.70",
    "d": "0.18"
  },
  {
    "a": "0.74",
    "b": "-0.14",
    "c": "0.22",
    "d": "-0.58"
  }
]
```

So the output will be as given below

```js
const out = [{
  property: a,
  minValue: -0.37,
  maxValue: .79,
  avg: 0.2733333333333334
}, {
  property: b,
  minValue: -.62,
  maxValue: .88,
  avg: -0.0016666666666666496
}, {
  property: c,
  minValue: -.96,
  maxValue: .07,
  avg: -0.21999999999999997
}, {
  property: d,
  minValue: -.58,
  maxValue: .74,
  avg: -0.028333333333333332
}]
```

So to get the output we iterate to the array and find the minimum, maximum, and average value of a, b , c and d and store it in a new array

Comment: in array there is always length of object is same and property key in object is also same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have
to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem
with your code.

Comment: btw, why do you have strings instead of numbers as type?

Comment: @romellem - sorry about that just posting my code, I am stuck so couldn't add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed a two step process -

1. Group the values of each property (using `reduce` for this)
2. Loop through all the properties and compute the required result.

```js
const array = [{    "a": "-0.06",    "b": "0.25",    "c": "-0.96",    "d": "-0.14"  },  {    "a": "-0.37",    "b": "0.01",    "c": "-0.77",    "d": "-0.09"  },{    "a": "0.01",    "b": "0.88",    "c": "-0.53",    "d": "-0.28"  },  {    "a": "0.53",    "b": "-0.62",    "c": "0.02",    "d": "0.74"  },  {    "a": "0.79",    "b": "-0.39",    "c": "0.70",    "d": "0.18"  },  {    "a": "0.74",    "b": "-0.14",    "c": "0.22",    "d": "-0.58"  }]

const out = [];

const newObj = array.reduce((prevValue, currValue) => {
  Object.keys(currValue).forEach((el) => {
    if (prevValue[el]) {
      prevValue[el].push(Number(currValue[el]));
    } else {
      prevValue[el] = [Number(currValue[el])];
    }
  });
  return prevValue;
}, {});

Object.keys(newObj).forEach((el) => {
  out.push({
    property: el,
    minValue: Math.min(...newObj[el]),
    maxValue: Math.max(...newObj[el]),
    avg: newObj[el].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / newObj[el].length
  });
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a two step approach. First i grouped the array on property using `reduce`. Then I performed a `map` on the grouped object to get the min, max and the average

```js
const array = [{    "a": "-0.06",    "b": "0.25",    "c": "-0.96",    "d": "-0.14"  },  {    "a": "-0.37",    "b": "0.01",    "c": "-0.77",    "d": "-0.09"  },{    "a": "0.01",    "b": "0.88",    "c": "-0.53",    "d": "-0.28"  },  {    "a": "0.53",    "b": "-0.62",    "c": "0.02",    "d": "0.74"  },  {    "a": "0.79",    "b": "-0.39",    "c": "0.70",    "d": "0.18"  },  {    "a": "0.74",    "b": "-0.14",    "c": "0.22",    "d": "-0.58"  }]

const grouped = array.reduce((acc,curr) => {
    Object.entries(curr).forEach(([property,v])=>{
    acc[property] = acc[property] || []
    acc[property].push(+v) //+ for convert to a number before pushing
  })
  return acc
},{})

const out = Object.entries(grouped).map(([property,v]) => {
    return {
    property,
    minValue: Math.min(...v),  // min of an array. v is the array of numbers
    maxValue: Math.max(...v),  //max of an array
    avg: v.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / v.length //average of an array
  }
})

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use Array.reduce and start with an object like the result but with extreme values, so for min there is the max. Or, depending on your spec it is undefined for any empty input array.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the idea. I always assume reduce is for adding

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function:
`

```
const createNewObj = (previous, current) => ({
  minValue: Math.min(previous, current,
  maxValue: Math.max(previous, current,
  total: previous + current,
  length: previous.length + 1,
  avg: (previous + current) / (previous.length + 1)
})

const default = {
  minValue: 0,
  maxValue: 0,
  total: 0,
  length: 0,
  avg: 0
}

array.reduce((previous, current) => {
a: createNewObj(previous[a], current[a]), 
b: createNewObj(previous[b], current[b]), 
c: createNewObj(previous[c], current[c]), 
d: createNewObj(previous[d], current[d])
}
, {
a: default,
b: default, 
c: default, 
d: default
})
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [{
    "a": "-0.06",
    "b": "0.25",
    "c": "-0.96",
    "d": "-0.14"
  },
  {
    "a": "-0.37",
    "b": "0.01",
    "c": "-0.77",
    "d": "-0.09"
  },
  {
    "a": "0.01",
    "b": "0.88",
    "c": "-0.53",
    "d": "-0.28"
  },
  {
    "a": "0.53",
    "b": "-0.62",
    "c": "0.02",
    "d": "0.74"
  },
  {
    "a": "0.79",
    "b": "-0.39",
    "c": "0.70",
    "d": "0.18"
  },
  {
    "a": "0.74",
    "b": "-0.14",
    "c": "0.22",
    "d": "-0.58"
  }
]

var out = [

]

Object.keys(array[0]).map(v=>{//this is so it runs for all 4 properties 
    let temp = {
  property:v
  }
  //sort array to get min and max
  let ary = [...array].sort((a,b)=>{
    return a-b
  })
  /* console.log(ary) */
  let avg = 0;
  ary.map(i=>{
    avg = avg+Number(i[v]);
  })
  temp.avg = avg/array.length
  temp.minValue = ary.pop()[v]
  temp.maxValue = ary.shift()[v]
  out.push(temp)
})
console.log(out)
```

see [fiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/bk97mc1z/)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code snippet you can use

```js
const array = [{
  "a": "-0.06",
  "b": "0.25",
  "c": "-0.96",
  "d": "-0.14"
},
{
  "a": "-0.37",
  "b": "0.01",
  "c": "-0.77",
  "d": "-0.09"
},
{
  "a": "0.01",
  "b": "0.88",
  "c": "-0.53",
  "d": "-0.28"
},
{
  "a": "0.53",
  "b": "-0.62",
  "c": "0.02",
  "d": "0.74"
},
{
  "a": "0.79",
  "b": "-0.39",
  "c": "0.70",
  "d": "0.18"
},
{
  "a": "0.74",
  "b": "-0.14",
  "c": "0.22",
  "d": "-0.58"
}
]


const grouped = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  for(let key in curr) {
    if(!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = []
    }else {
      acc[key].push(curr[key])
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, {})

const output = []
for(let key in grouped) {
  const obj = {}
  const integers = grouped[key].map(el => parseFloat(el, 10))
  obj["property"] = key
  obj["minValue"] = Math.min(...integers)
  obj["maxValue"] = Math.max(...integers)
  obj["avg"] = (integers.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr) ) / integers.length;
  output.push(obj)
}
console.log(output)
```